# How to replace last dot in a string using a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to replace the last dot in a String using a regular expression.

Let's say I have the following String:

```
String string = "hello.world.how.are.you!";
```

I want to replace the last dot with an exclamation mark such that the result is:

```
"hello.world.how.are!you!"
```

I have tried various expressions using the method `String.replaceAll(String, String)` without any luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way would be:

```
string = string.replaceAll("^(.*)\\.(.*)$","$1!$2");
```

Alternatively you can use negative lookahead as:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\.(?!.*\\.)","!");
```

[**Regex in Action**](http://www.ideone.com/A1L9M)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I would never have come up with that monster.

Comment: The fact that it's a monster (your words, not mine) is probably a good argument for _not_ using it :-) Still, if it works, it should be accepted since you did ask for a regex solution.

Comment: I'm greedy as the pattern and I approve :)
Nice use of greedy .*

Comment: Why not make the second quantifier reluctant, as in `^(.*)\\.(.*?)$` ?

Answer (score 10):

Although you can use a regex, it's sometimes best to step back and just do it the old-fashioned way. I've always been of the belief that, if you can't think of a regex to do it in about two minutes, it's probably not suited to a regex solution.

No doubt get some wonderful regex answers here. Some of them may even be readable :-)

You can use [`lastIndexOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to get the last occurrence and [`substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to build a new string: This complete program shows how:

```
public class testprog {
    public static String morph (String s) {
        int pos = s.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos >= 0)
            return s.substring(0,pos) + "!" + s.substring(pos+1);
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println (morph("hello.world.how.are.you!"));
        System.out.println (morph("no dots in here"));
        System.out.println (morph(". first"));
        System.out.println (morph("last ."));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
hello.world.how.are!you!
no dots in here
! first
last !
```

Comment: Yeah I had a solution using StringBuilder and replacing based on the index of the last dot.  But I wanted to get it done using a regular expression if possible hence the question.

Comment: Just as an FYI, my previous solution using StringBuilder looked like this: StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string); builder.replace(lastDotIndex, lastDotIndex + 1, "!"); String newString = builder.toString();

Answer (score 7):

The regex you need is `\\.(?=[^.]*$)`. the `?=` is a lookahead assertion

```
"hello.world.how.are.you!".replace("\\.(?=[^.]*$)", "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[.]$", "");
```