# How to convert CSV floating numbers to double in java

Tags: java, database, excel, csv

Hi i have a CSV file that contains rows like this

Jacop , "Assistant",150,75

i want to convert 3rd column to 150.75 in java

Should i write a function for this .Or is there another way?

thanks

Comment: This answer explains how to capture the last occurrence in a line using a regex (substitute): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094024/how-to-replace-last-dot-in-a-string-using-a-regular-expression. This answer explains how to convert a string to a number in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097332/convert-a-string-to-number-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick idea:

- get that value as String
- replace "," with "." in String
- try to parse double with Double.parseDouble

Answer (score 1):

UBe careful of floating point arithmetic errors, but this is the right idea:

```
int a = Integer.valueOf("150"); // Since your numbers are coming from a CSV
int b = Integer.valueOf("75");

double c = c = (a * 100 + b) / 100.0;
=> 150.75
```

Note, the value if 100 is there assuming that your number to the right of the decimal is always two digits. So, if that isn't constant, don't use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple regular expression search and replace in your text file (using sed or whatever) to convert the last comma to a decimal point should work fine.

Then use opencsv to pull it all in:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/