# Remove the lastest dot character ( . ) in word using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have some problems where my program must remove lastest dot character ( . ) using regex in Java.

Comment: show your attempts..

Comment: Why does it have to be using regex?

Comment: You get the answer by doing a simple search..

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094024/how-to-replace-last-dot-in-a-string-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.') - 1);
```

As per reference of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) in the oracle documentation should work for this.  If there are expectations of characters following the '.' then use:

```
String str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.') - 1) + str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

My apologies for ignoring the requested regex aspect of this question.  However, I will note that Google is overloaded with the regex pattern required for this functionality...

Edit:
I've included a stackoverflow link, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094024/how-to-replace-last-dot-in-a-string-using-a-regular-expression).  Please do searches before requesting information.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like this

```
someString.substring(0, someString.length()-1);
```

Don't forget to use `trim()` if extra [whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) is expected to appear at either end.